# Azure Websites - Scale Up vs. Scale Out

Tags: azure

Has anyone seen any analysis or info on when it is ideal to scale out vs. scale up. When does one make more sense than the other.

Currently, 2 small instances will cost the same as one medium under both the standard and basic modes.

Is having 2 small instances and thus 4 GB of RAM, the same as having 1 Medium instance with 4 GB of RAM (but without an SLA); and the same for cores. All the other features are the same.

Does either CPU pressure or memory pressure, two easy metrics, dictate which way to scale?

And, in this case, scaling out does not present an issue as far as apps/sites working on different machines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: Just to correct one of your assertions regarding Azure Web Sites.  You do NOT need 2 instances in order to get an SLA.  You only need one.  (the reason is because with Azure Web Sites, any of our instances can serve any site, and we can switch over traffic to another site if needed immediately, with only the cost of application cold start).

Comment: Interesting, I could have sworn that I saw somewhere that 2 instances were required. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you can, always try to scale out vs. scale up.  Chances of one VM going down due to a reboot/upgrade/etc and having catastrophic downtime are much bigger than 0... while the overhead of running two VM's and load-balancing between them is minimal and chances of you having both VM's down are much much smaller.

In addition if you ever need 3 servers, scaling up with medium servers will not yield the right granularity.

Comment: While scaling out will often give you high availability for little to no extra effort, it doesn't necessarily do so, and scaling up doesn't exclude you from adding high availability options.  (Just take a look at Stack overflows architecture for a good example of scaling up https://stackexchange.com/performance).

Answer (score 0):

Having  2 small instances of 1.75 GB each IS NOT the same as having 1 Medium instance with 3.5 GB of RAM. It is better to have a MEDIUM instance because 3.5 GB is now available to applications instead of just 1.75 GB. Also, each OS takes some RAM away approximately 800-900 MB. Having two instances takes RAm of two OS.

Comment: We ran into problems like this when we switched to multiple small machines on kubernetes. Large downloads that were handled by one large machine stopped working as the smaller machines didn't have the memory capacity to handle them. Like everything in tech, it's a trade off.